# New line and indent without electric mode

Tags: key-bindings, indentation, minor-mode, electric-indent

I have come to hate the inconsistency of the electric indent mode and I haven't much of a clue about how it works anyways, so I've disabled it and am trying to get the desired behavior from scratch. I want emacs to indent me to the previous line's indentation level *and do nothing else* on `RET`. [`indent-relative`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Relative-Indent.html) seems to be the right function for the job. Seems easy enough, and yet I cannot get it to work. This is what I have thus far:

```lisp
(electric-indent-mode -1)

(defun my-newline-and-indent ()
  (interactive)
  (newline)
  (indent-relative))
```

I used to bind this with `global-set-key`, but hooking it to the specific modes I use is a better idea ([found here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ForceReturnIndent)):

```lisp
(defun my-keys ()
  (local-set-key [(return)] 'my-newline-and-indent))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-keys)
```

[The above does not indent new lines in C.](https://i.imgur.com/sbXGWzc.mp4) I also tried the same thing with `indent-relative-maybe`, but that doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit: now that I got it working thanks to @Tyler, the function that better fits the behavior I want is actually `indent-relative-maybe` (though I can't find any documentation on it online). `indent-relative` indents to the last whitespace on the previous line, which is too zealous. For example, here is how it indents in F90 mode:

```
program test
        _
```

By contrast, `indent-relative-maybe` seems to only indent to the first non-whitespace character.

Comment: Does the built-in `newline-and-indent` do what you want?

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you provide an example of C code and show us where pressing return doesn't give you the indentation you expect?

Comment: @Tyler I added a short demonstration video of the behavior I mean. Electric indent would have started a new line on the 4th column after that comment, which is also what I want to replicate

Comment: When I run your code, and enter the elisp you have above, this works as expected. I enter `int main() {`, press enter, and the cursor moves to the next line under the `m` in main. Pressing two slashes and return, the cursor moves to the next line under the first slash.

Comment: Are you sure you set `(electric-indent-mode -1)`? I don't think emacs would automatically indent C code after braces with electric indent disabled, and the code I posted should not do that either

Comment: I just tried again from `emacs -Q`, and turned off electric-indent-mode explicitly. Same behaviour as I described before. It does automatically indent after braces, that's what `my-line-and-indent` does. After you insert the newline, it calls `indent-relative`, which after the first brace lines up with the `m`.

Comment: I have no clue how you're getting these results. [Here is a video of me using nothing but the code snippet as the init file and still getting nothing.](https://i.imgur.com/azVGlz6.mp4) What could be causing this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126528/discussion-between-andrii-kozytskyi-and-tyler).

Comment: You've misspelled `c-mode-hook` in your init file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a terminal the value of `[(return)]` doesn't apply. You need to use `(kbd "RET")` instead. (or probably other variations would do, but not `[(return)]`).

Comment: But he's called the function: `(electric-indent-mode -1)`.  And the init file copied directly from the question seems to work fine (actually, you are right about the terminal bit: I checked in a gui session). The problem I saw was that he misspelled `c-mode-hook` in the init file that he used in his video.

Comment: @NickD you're right, I was obviously not paying close enough attention!

Comment: Well, I wasn't paying close enough attention either, so I cannot throw stones :-)